# IGP with MultiMonitor ON breaks bootloader?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, multiple-monitors, bsod, bootloader

I am having some very strange problem.

My setup first:

Lenovo PC with i7 Gen. 4
Intel HD Graphics 4600 with 2x Displayports
16gb RAM

1. Monitor: HP Elitedisplay
2. Monitor: Benq RL2755

OS: Win10 Professional

So my problem:

Everything was working fine with the first monitor. Then I bought the Benq monitor, and plugged it in normally on the second Display port of the iGPU. After 2-3 days, I noticed my system get slower and freeze from time to time for 10-15 seconds. So I thought a reboot may resolve the problem. But then boom, BSOD. Windows startup repair did nothing and repair with boot usb also failed with the message: „No recognized file system found!“ I tried every suggested command, be it CHKDSK or sfc /scannow, but with no success. Luckily I had recently made a backup of my SSD. So I plugged in the duplicate SSD and it worked. But the next day, the system froze again, this time permanently. I had to perform a hard reboot, and you guessed it, BSOD with „No recognizable file system found!“ again.

Both of my SSDs just broken. Now I performed a clean install on a new SSD and at the moment I am using it with my main monitor only. It is working good, but I am too afraid to plug the second monitor back in.

Have you any idea what the problem may be or how I can somehow bring my old SSDs back to life?

P.s.: the SSD work normal as an external drive, so I did not lose access to my data, only the boot is broken.

P.p.s.: By system „freezing“ I meant the image freezing and any audio playing turning into a high pitched „BZZZ“